# Changing font within a `TikZ` environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following figure, I have a point labeled `(2, 16/3)`.  I would like the font of the `2` to be `scriptsize` and the font of the `16` and `3` to be `tiny`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in, height=3in, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2,xmax=8,
    ymin=-3,ymax=11,
    restrict y to domain=-3:11,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[latex-latex, domain=-2:8] {(-4/3)*x + 8};
\addplot[latex-latex, dashed, domain=-2:8] {16/3};

\coordinate (A) at (2,16/3);
\coordinate (label_for_ell) at (8,-8/3);
\coordinate (label_for_horizontal_line) at (8,16/3);


\draw[fill] (A) circle [radius=1.5pt];

\end{axis}

\draw node[anchor=west, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(label_for_horizontal_line) +(0.15,0)$){$y=\dfrac{16}{3}$};
\draw node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(label_for_ell) +({atan(-4/3)}:0.15)$){$y = \dfrac{-4}{3}x + 8$};

\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (A) -- ($(A) +({0.5*(atan(-4/3)+180)}:0.75)$) node[anchor=south west, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=0] {$\left(2, \, \raisebox{0.2em}{$\tiny{16}$}/\raisebox{-0.2em}{$\tiny{3}$}\right)$};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, intersections}

\makeatletter% stolen from memoir.cls
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\slashfracstyle}[1]{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont #1}}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\slashfrac}[2]{\leavevmode
  \raise.5ex\hbox{\slashfracstyle{#1}}\kern-.13em/%
  \kern-.15em\lower.25ex\hbox{\slashfracstyle{#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex]
% coordinate axes
\draw[<->] (-2,0) -- (10,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[<->] (0,-2) -- (0,10) node[above] {$y$};
% line (-4/3)*x + 8
\draw[name path=A,
      thick,latex-latex, domain=-1:7] plot (\x,-4*\x/3 + 8)
                                           node[right] {$y=\dfrac{-4}{3}x + 8$};
\draw[name path=B,
      dashed,<->] (-1,16/3) -- + (8,0) node[right] {$y=\dfrac{18}{3}$};
\path[name intersections={of=A and B, by={d}}]
         node[circle, fill, inner sep=2pt,
            pin=60:{(2,\slashfrac{15}{3})}] at (d) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Graph is redrawn in pure TikZ picture, since code in it is -- of course according to my opinion -- simpler and shorter. With pgf plots is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, intersections}

\makeatletter% stolen from memoir.cls
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\slashfracstyle}[1]{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont #1}}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\slashfrac}[2]{\leavevmode
  \raise.5ex\hbox{\slashfracstyle{#1}}\kern-.13em/%
  \kern-.15em\lower.25ex\hbox{\slashfracstyle{#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex]
\begin{axis}[width=3in, height=3in, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2,xmax=8,
    ymin=-3,ymax=11,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=1em,right},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=1em, above}
]
% lines
\addplot[name path=A,thick,<->, domain=-2:8] {(-4/3)*x + 8}
                node[right] {$y=-\dfrac{4}{3}x + 8$};;
\addplot[name path=B,dashed,<->, domain=-2:8] {16/3}
                node[right] {$y=\dfrac{18}{3}$};
% intersection
\path[name intersections={of=A and B, by={d}}]
         node[circle, fill, inner sep=2pt,
            pin=60:{(2,\slashfrac{15}{3})}] at (d) {};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as with first, pure TikZ example.

**Edit:**
If you for some reason don't like to have code for definition `\slashfrac` in a document preamble (where is natural space for it), you can move it inside `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, intersections}


\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex]
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\slashfracstyle}[1]{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont #1}}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\slashfrac}[2]{\leavevmode
  \raise.5ex\hbox{\slashfracstyle{#1}}\kern-.13em/%
  \kern-.15em\lower.25ex\hbox{\slashfracstyle{#2}}}
\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{axis}[width=3in, height=3in, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2,xmax=8,
    ymin=-3,ymax=11,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=1em,right},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=1em, above}
]
% lines
\addplot[name path=A,thick,<->, domain=-2:8] {(-4/3)*x + 8}
                node[right] {$y=-\dfrac{4}{3}x + 8$};;
\addplot[name path=B,dashed,<->, domain=-2:8] {16/3}
                node[right] {$y=\dfrac{18}{3}$};
% intersection
\path[name intersections={of=A and B, by={d}}]
         node[circle, fill, inner sep=2pt,
            pin=60:{(2,\slashfrac{15}{3})}] at (d) {};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see that you used the `intersections` package to get the "intersection" of the two lines. Nice. By the way, the intersection is at `(2, 16/3)`.  You have `(2, 15/3)`.

Comment: I don't want to have this command from `memoir.cls` in the preamble.  My guess is that I will be issuing it only once in a particular file.  How do I adapt it to the node command that instructs `TikZ` to typeset the label?  (I had not seen the `\leavevmode` command before your response.   I found the following comment from Christian Feuersaenger. "The external library now typesets as horizontal material by issueing `\leavevmode`. This fixes an inconsistency with the normal tikzpictures."  I am not sure why this command is needed.)

Comment: well, I only suggest working example. if you don't liked it, than don't used it. maybe someone offer solution which will better fit to your expectation. you also can search for packages, which offer similar design fractions.

Comment: The display that you get is what I want.

Comment: Can you post the same code except remove the command from `memoir.cls` in the preamble and put a `node` command in the `TikZ` environment for the label of the intersection?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire, I need some time to rethinking your comments, but not find anything better as I already proposed, however if you like, you can move definition inside `tikzpicture` as I show in edited answer. I'm sorry but beside this can't help you further.

Comment: Your code gives me the display that I want.  I will accept it as the answer.  I am looking for simpler code to change the font for specific characters within a `TikZ` environment ... or within an `equation` environment.

Comment: This piece of code have been designed by the best TeX experts (not me :-) ) so I doubt that you find anything better. However see if the package `nicefrac` offer what you like to have. Package is old (from 1998) and I never use it (for my needs I use `memoir` document class, which has integrated `slashfrac` so i don't need any special package for this. Happy TeX-ing!